# south migration making incorrect initial schemamigration

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I'm trying to run migration by south,
But when I run : `manage.py schemamigration <my_app> --initial`
it makes wrong modifications, creating "`Added model treinoclub_app.Endereco
Added model treinoclub_app.Academia`".

But I didn't make any changes for this table.

Comment: did you run a `./manage.py migrate treinoclub_app` after the `schemamigration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--initial` is not about detecting changes, you shouldn't expect it to.

It takes the current state of the tables and exports them as create table statements to get your first migration off the ground such that on a new install, you simply run "python manage.py migrate" to build your tables from start to finish.

No matter how many times you run `--initial`, it will generate these migrations with full table output. Again, it is not about detecting anything - it simply outputs the current state of the tables and is intended to be used as the "intitial/first" migration.